# Antlr4 'no viable alternative at input' with my grammar

Tags: java, grammar, antlr4, rule

I'm trying to use antlr4 and I have the following grammar :

```
grammar Comp;

start : 'ca\n';

ID  :   [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
OTHER : (~'\n')* '\n' ;
```

If I send the lexem 'ca\n' it works.
But with the rule :

```
start : 'ca' '\n';
```

or

```
start : 'ca' NEWLINE;
```

the lexem is not recongnized. Why ?

Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: The lexer will always match the longest rule it can find. The issue is that the rule, "OTHER", is capturing the whole string as one token. OTHER will capture "ca\n" which prevents the "start" rule from capturing the separate tokens of "ca" and "\n".